# ROW_NUMBER() in old mySql version

Tags: mysql

I have similiar queries to create rno column with row number identity for Postgres and Oracle.

```
(select 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) AS RNO
      , subQuery.* 
from $TableName subQuery ) AS newTable".
```

following the docs this query doesnt work in mySql 5.6 version. I am getting this error:

```
SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=12142) You have an error in your SQL
syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near 
'(ORDER BY NULL) AS RNO, subQuery.* from qbf.User subQuery )
AS newTable WHERE 1=' at line 1
```

How can i use this query in mySql for same purposes without upgrading mySql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can achieve this by using [variables](https://blog.devart.com/mysql-variables-html.html#:%7E:text=The%20SET%20statement%20syntax%20for,performance%20for%20user%2Ddefined%20variables.) and assigning values to them as you go on:

```
SELECT 
id, 
@row_num:=@row_num+1 
FROM 
(SELECT id, @row_num:=0 FROM TableName) newTable
```

This query will simply give you the equivalent of `ROW_NUMBER()`
You need to play a little bit if you want to apply conditions or perform some other operations.

Comment: looks good. I can convert it to long if needed? think the result id double. in addition, if I want to start count from 0, should I change the @rum_num:=-1 correct ? Thanks

Comment: As I said, I have just mentioned a basic guideline for you to begin with. You'll need to play with it a little bit. And yes you can use -1 to get started from 0. Also I mentioned `id` for just an example. You'll be fetching your desired columns there

Comment: @JohnDoe *I can convert it to long if needed?* `.. (SELECT id, @row_num:=CAST(0 AS UNSIGNED) FROM TableName) ..`. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html *"the default result type of a variable is based on its type at the beginning of the statement."*